# Javascript won't show up

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to include my first Javascript snippet to see how it works in a browser. But when I add these lines in my HTML code (directly in the body, even if I know there are better ways), nothing happens. I save the file as HTML and open it up in Chrome

```js
var greeting = function(name) {
  console.log("Great to see you" + " " + name);
};
greeting("Waldo")
```

Comment: replace "console.log" with "alert"

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/o5n79qfx/  Are you getting any errors on the console?  Is JavaScript disabled in your browser?

Comment: Open you console in your browser. It's f12 in Chrome and then click the `Console` tab. That's where `console.log` writes to.

Comment: Question! Are you using a CMS like WordPress, etc?

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys! It was actually working, it was writitng in the Console and replacing with "alert" it has shown a welcome box. 
Just one question, out of personal curosity: wha's the point of printing out something in the Console?

Comment: For reference, see [Outputting text to the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).

Comment: I'm not using ARL, I heard of some conflict between JS and Wordpress. Does using a CMS change Javascript's behavior?

Comment: Because sometimes you need have messages for yourself (don't for user). In this case you will write your messages in the console (and it won't showed to user).

Comment: @skY_io When you start *debugging* (act of searching for errors) it will become pretty handy to show variables or if and *if* actually works, stuff like that.

Comment: @skY_io The point of printing something in the console is that it doesn't affect anything for the user, but it helps you figure out what is happening in the code. It's especially helpful for debugging, because you can print different variables or add print statements inside functions to see when (if) they are being run.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, really clear. I am glad I am here!

Answer (score 1):

It does works, tho you need to access the JS console, which is inside the DevTools of chrome.

If you want a more *in your face* approach, change it for alert.

Answer (score 0):

Replace console.log with alert, put a semicolon after
    greeting("Waldo");
And remove the white space between
    function (name)
So it will be
    function(name)

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("stuff")` logs a message to the developer console. You open the console through the menu on most browsers (on Chrome for example hit menu->more tools->developer tools->console). This will show you the result of any `console.log`s as well as errors, and you can run Javascript code in the console.

As others have suggested, `alert("stuff")` is a good replacement if you don't want to deal with the console. It will show a dialog box (popup) instead of printing the text to the console.

Answer (score 0):

First: are you wrapping these lines of code with the `<script>....</script>` tags?
If so, just open your browser console with F12 and you should see the result of the function.